# Cython: How to assign a C function to a Python/ Cython variable?

Tags: python, c, callback, cython

At the moment I'm trying out Cython and want to see, if I can write my whole project in this language, unfortunately I have quite a problem.

I've got a C library lets call it "lib.c" from which I import a function:

```
cdef extern from 'lib.c':
    double compute(double params[7], double IN[2])
```

Now I want to assign this function to an arbitrary variable which does not have to be accessible from Python:

```
K = compute
```

which is no problem at all in Python, but on compiling I get the error

Cannot convert 'double (double *, double *)' to Python object.

Wrapping the C function with a Cython function does not work either. If e.g. I do

```
cdef double _K_wrap(double params[7], double IN[2]):
    return compute(params, IN)

K = _K_wrap
```

I get the same error.

Any suggestions of how to assign a C function to a Python/ Cython variable would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

OK, I just tried the suggestion of hivert:

```
ctypedef double (*Func)(double params[7], double IN[2])

cdef class FunctionHandler:
    cdef Func K
    def __cinit__(self, Func f):
        self.K = f
    def __call__(self, double params[7], double IN[2]):
        return self.K(params, IN)

K = FunctionHandler(compute)
```

This results in the same error. Probably I did something wrong in the __call__ method.

Comment: Do you want the function for be accessible from Python ?

Comment: I clarified things about K. It's just an arbitrary variable which I want to assign different functions to, depending on some input.

The function does not necessarily have to be accessible from Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap your function in a `cdef class`:

```
cdef extern from 'lib.c':
    double compute(double params[7], double IN[2])

ctypedef double (*Func)(double params[7], double IN[2])

cdef class FunctionHandler:
    cdef Func K

    # def __cinit__(self, Func f):
    #    self.K = f

    def __init__(self):
        raise Exception, "FunctionHandler cannot be instanciated from Python"

    def __call__(self, list pm, list inn):
        cdef double parm[7], cin[2]
        for i in range(7):
            parm[i] = pm[i]
        for i in range(2):
            cin[i] = inn[i]
        return self.K(parm, cin)

cdef CreateFunctionHandler(Func f):
    cdef FunctionHandler res = FunctionHandler.__new__(FunctionHandler)
    res.K = f
    return res

example = CreateFunctionHandler(compute)
```

then

```
>>> import wrap
>>> wrap.example([1.1]+range(6), [4.4, 1.])
8.64
```

Comment: Could you write out the \_\_call\_\_ function? - I still get conversion errors.

Comment: It depends on how you get your parameters from Python. Can you show some of your attempts ? Maybe in another question.

Comment: Sorry I was too fast. Here is a corrected code which compile on my computer. Note that I didn't actually tested it.

Comment: Great! This finally works, thanks alot for your help. I was about to decide against using Cython in my project. But your answer actually taught my quite a lot about Cython. Maybe I'll get the grasp of it now. I'm sorry I can't vote up your answer. My rep is still too low.

Comment: You are welcome ! I just voted up your question, this should give you some REP ;-)